# Problems with response of the form after upload file

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

when i receive a response from the server without that is not handle by AJAX i have a problem to catch the data, normally the data goes to the target but that only happens in Chrome, the other browsers open a new tab and insert the response in the new tab, my question is how i can avoid that? i wanna insert on the target, the code below is the code of the page and the javascript that trigger the submit.

Here is the code of the form.

```
<div>
  <form id='uploadFrm' action='/'enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST' target='frame_trgt'>
<input id='1_inp' name='upfile' type='file' />
<input id='pathFile' type='input' name='path' />
<input id='uploadFile' type='submit' /><br />
 </form>
 <iframe id='frame_trgt' name='frame_trgt' />
</div>
```

Here is the code of the JavaScript that handle the upload file.

```
$('[name=upfile]').change(function(event){
        $("#pathFile").attr('value', getData('carpet'));
        $("#uploadFile").trigger('click');
    });
```

Comment: I do not understand the question. Can you describe again what you want, and what you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe you just need to close your iframe tag

```
<iframe id='frame_trgt' name='frame_trgt'></iframe>
```